# Epson Stylus TX110 ink levels

Tags: drivers, lubuntu, printing, epson

I'm running Lubuntu 14.4 on my Acer Travelmate 2490. I finally managed to get my Epson Stylus T110 to print, but the print utility does not show the ink levels (one of the ink cartridges has now run out, so the printer refuses to print :-(

I have tried MtInk, but this does not support my printer (and I have no idea how to drive the thing!)

Any help would be greatly appreciated (as simple as possible please, I can cut and paste, but that is as far as my terminal-skills go)

Answer (score 1):

Epson finally made an Utility for Linux to show ink levels and for printer maintenance.

You can download it from [Epson Drivers Site](http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/search/01/search/searchModule).

Search for your printer model, select Linux as OS and download Epson Printer Utility.

You will need `epson-printer-utility_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_i386.deb` if your sistem is 32-bit, or `epson-printer-utility_1.0.0-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb` for a 64-bit system.

Download the file to your Home folder and run in terminal

```
sudo dpkg -i epson-printer-utility*.deb
```

The utility can be started from terminal by

```
epson-printer-utility
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the empty cartridge manually. Open the tray, look at the 3 cartridges, press the cancel button for 5 seconds or so, then wait for the printer to show you which is the empty one, it will point it with a little arrow carved with a drop